# Firefox Mac preventing video with overlay from playing

Tags: html, css, firefox

Unfortunately YouTube only counts views to videos when you click directly on the YouTube player itself. This is to prevent fraudulently high view counts. One technique if you don't want to show the YouTube player initially is to put an opaque overlay and graphic over the top with `pointer-events: none`. When the user clicks on your overlay they will actually be clicking on the YouTube video so the view is counted. You then capture the 'playing' event and hide the overlay exposing the player underneath.

I have a graphic on my homepage and when you click it plays a YouTube video. Before anyone cries 'clickjacking' I'm not trying to trick anyone - there's a play button in the graphic so you know it's a video.

This works completely fine for me for everything except FireFox on Mac OS. I am using the latest version - currently 34.0.5 in my tests.

#### Demo page : http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B3INRRYhLi7cVHNKTzhMdnRjT3M

- If you run this in Chrome / FireFox Windows / Recent IE version and click on the green overlay the video will play and you will hear music.
- Note: Of course in my real page I capture the `isplaying` event and hide the overlay.

Firefox is obviously doing some kind of clickjacking protection. If it thinks that you're trying to trick the user with an overlay over the video then it won't play it. However it is really bizarre to me that it doesn't also do this on Windows.

There are two ways to allow the video to play on Mac FireFox - both involve partially revealing the Youtube video underneath:

- If you click 'Change opacity to 75%' it will show the video through underneath. If you then click it then it will play just fine.
- If you click 'Make overlay smaller' it will make the overlay not completely cover the video. Clicking on it will then play just fine.

The most bizarre thing of all - when you view it in an iframe it works just fine (this is why I'm using a [GoogleDrive link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) above that opens fullscreen) and not something like codepen/jsfiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgrZNN

I'm really looking for a workaround that doesn't involve `if (firefox && mac)`. If this is documented somewhere in mozilla docs I haven't found it.

PS. Obviously browsers without `pointer-events` have to be treated differently with an on-click event. That is not shown in this example.

(I'm using Browserstack.com to test, but it does the same on a real mac.)

Comment: If you don't receive any answers I suggest reach for FF devs on irc.mozilla.orc #firefox during California working hours.

Comment: I'm running 34.0.5 on mac osx Yosemite and its working just fine. Reset your browser?

Comment: @NicholasYoung thanks for testing. I don't have a mac but on both my bosses mac and Browserstack it doesn't work. Just to confirm you're saying you open the page and click on the green and the music plays immediately? Do you have any plugins such as adblock/noscript ?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver My firefox is completely stock without any addons, I opened it up in 34.0.5 clicked the green box and the video started playing

Comment: @NicholasYoung are you clicking on the google link and not the codepen link. for some reason the frameset is allowing it to work in the codepen link. if you click the googledrive link it should fail

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I'm running everything off of the google link, I also ran the site in browserstack and its working

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Wait, one second i might have a fix for you.

Comment: i've ran it literally hundreds of times in browserstack over several days and not got it to work. that's very bizarre :-/

Comment: @NicholasYoung that's exactly why the button is there. Firefox is clever enough to see that it is opaque and try to stop a clickjacking attempt, which is fair enough if you have a clickjacking plugin, but not for a stock browser on only one platform

Comment: This is indeed a very odd behaviour, the blocking seems prevalent even in an iframe over localhost. So no idea what it is that Codepen and the like do differently (or at least how FF treats them differently). Taking that source direct from Codepen (where it works fine for me) and running over localhost (where it doesn't). baffling... unless certain hosts are exempt? but that would be even stranger...

Comment: Maybe I need to try my own frameset / iframes. I wondered if it could be something to do with the doctype but I think I have the same as they use. I've tried many other 'codepens' like jsfiddle / jsbin and get the same behavior. Was very frustrating (and ironic) just how hard it was to find a way to publish a broken page

Comment: @Simon_Weaver ~ I think I've found why Codepen (and similar) work, still can't explain what exactly is going on, but check my updated answer for details. It would be nice to find a post from Mozilla outlining what this block is.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same issue Firefox Mac (and have yet to upgrade to Yosemite), but it seems to me you have pretty much already solved your own problem. The simplest solution that I can see would be to add an extra overlay layer beneath your current one and set them both to opacity 0.98 (which seems to be the highest you can go and still have the click work — at least in my tests).

Obviously it will depend on what you hope to show on your overlay, but for my tests locally I set the under-overlay (sorry, ridiculous name) to black. This meant that the video underneath was imperceptible. You could probably even go a little lower with the opacity and still block everything out with two layers, just in case the opacity thresholds for the click blocking are different across versions of Firefox.

```
.x-overlay {
  opacity: 0.98;
  ...
}

.x-under-overlay {
  opacity: 0.98;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

> **NOTE:** One downside to be aware of when using even slight opacity. For certain browsers (or at least versions of browsers) text that appears in a layer that has opacity can end up with buggy or missing anti-aliasing. But this mainly occurred in much older versions of Firefox and Chrome.

### update

Ok this was driving me a bit round the wall, or up the bend, or which ever strange phrase that can be used to describe the experience of continually expecting one thing, but consistently getting another... which has eerie similarities to [the definition of crazy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=insanity).

*Why on **[insert home planet here]** did this work for Codepen, but not in my own localhost-served iframe...??*

After attempting a number of different things I spotted the `sandbox` attribute, which I really should have noticed before; especially considering all the strange trickery it can enable and disable with native browser processes. A quick trial and a few errorings later, and it seems what allows this to work for most of those online-code-fiddlers is the following:

```
<iframe src="index.html" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Still haven't found out exactly why, but if I enable the above on my localhost frame it starts working without the need for the opacity trick. I guess it must cause Firefox to route through a different process, or perhaps it just disables some kind of cross-origin clickjacking protection.

A very odd state of affairs... this is the kind of oddity I would expect from Chrome! Not good ol' Firefox.

Comment: hi pebbl. I did wonder about doing that. I didn't actually get round to testing to see if two 98% overlays would trick the browser but glad to know it seems to work. it's definitely an option, although so is `if (firefox && mac)` due to the relatively low percentage of people with firefox+mac :-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver ~ Hi! Yes very true, although browser sniffing is probably more prone to issues than an invisible layer -- especially when attempting to detect a browser and an OS together ;) This layer approach also doesn't seem to interfere with the other browsers either (in my tests -- even in Opera :) so no real need to apply it conditionally (save for browsers that don't support `pointer-events` as you say).

Comment: redesigning the site and facing the same again! but now it looks like Chrome is doing the same kind of blocking. I did come up with an additional 'hack' and that is to split the overlay into 2 or more pieces.